# SQL query for the words starting and ending with same letter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a SQL Query to select the column having the first and last same letter. Example: 'Dead','Daily Mail Launched'

```
Select [EventName], CASE  
When [EventName] like '%[A-Z]' and [EventName] like '[A-Z]%'THEN 'Same Letter' end
from [dbo].[tblEvent]
```

Answer (score 7):

Don't use `LIKE`, use `LEFT()` and `RIGHT()`:

```
where left(eventname, 1) = right(eventname, 1)
```

Comment: The wouldn't exclude values that begin and end with the same non-alpha character... Adding **AND LIKE '[a-Z]%'** to your good solution would.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, When you put left or right functions in where condition, then it will be Non-sargable. Table scan will occur. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @RGS . . . Well, yes.  But so is a `LIKE` pattern that starts with a wildcard.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Have a look on below link about trigram wildcard search. https://sqlperformance.com/2017/09/sql-performance/sql-server-trigram-wildcard-search.

Comment: @RGS . . . n-grams are a tried-and-true technique for doing such searches.  Postgres has supported them for many years:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html.